# Borrar productId con Nodejs & Mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose, mongodb

Buenas! Estoy desarrollando una mini `API RESTFul` con `Node.js` y `Mongodb`. La cuestion es la siguiente, estoy desarrollando 4 funciones basicas para mi API que serian `GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE`.

Estoy teniendo un error al realizar el `DELETE` y es el siguiente error:

`Cannot DELETE /api/product/58feb76ed70f040be8d69e6d`

Y este seria mi codigo:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('./modelos/product');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/product', (req, res) => {
  Product.find({}, (err, products) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar peticion ${error}`});
    if(!products) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No existen productos'});

    res.send(200, {products});
  });
});

app.get('/api/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
  let productId = req.params.productId;

  Product.findById(productId, (error, product) => {
    if (error) return res.status(500).send({message: `Erro al realizar peticion ${error}`});
    if(!product) return res.status(404).send({message: 'El producto no existe!'});

    res.status(200).send({product});
  });
});

app.post('/api/product', (req, res) => {
  console.log('POST /api/product');
  console.log(req.body);

  let product = new Product()
  product.name = req.body.name
  product.picture = req.body.picture
  product.price = req.body.price
  product.category = req.body.category
  product.description = req.body.description

  product.save((err, productStored) =>{
    if (err)res.status(500).send({message: `Error al salvar en la base de datos:  ${err}`});

    res.status(200).send({product: productStored});
  });
});

app.put('/api/product:productId', (req, res) => {

});

app.delete('/api/product:productId', (req, res) => {
  let productId = req.params.productId;

  Produc.findById(productId, (err, product) =>{
    if(err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al borrar el producto ${err}`});

    product.remove(err =>{
      if(err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al borrar el producto ${err}`});
      res.status(200).send({message: 'El producto ha sido eliminado'});
    })
  })
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shop', (error, res) =>{
  if(error){
    return console.log(`Error al conectar a la base de datos: ${error}` );
  }
  console.log("Conexion a la base de datos correcta");

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API REST corriendo en http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Estoy cargando los productos a la API de prueba con `POSTMAN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema:

Te esta faltando agregar una barra (`/`) para separar el parámetro `:productId` en la ruta `/api/product`.

### Solución:

```
app.delete('/api/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
```

**PD:** El mismo error esta en el `app.put`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos! Ahora veo el codigo para solucionarlo!